# image setting in layout for android api 10

Tags: android, image

I have implemented a graphical interface for an app in Android API 14, in which I position a figure in certain position. I am using the following code to do that:

```
fig1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fig1);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lpsen1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lpsen1.topMargin = 10;
lpsen1.leftMargin = 10;
fig1.setLayoutParams(lpsen1);
```

I am using a FrameLayout in .xml layout file, and the code for the figure is the following:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/fig1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/yellowdot"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
    android:maxWidth="10dp" 
    android:maxHeight="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />
```

It works fine, but now I am trying to implement it in android API 10 and it does not place the figure where I need it to be.

Can someone tell me how to do it right?

Thanks in advance.

Gus.

Comment: Please define "does not work at all"

Comment: Well, the code I posted does not place the figure where I want to, for API 10 (but it does place the figure correctly for API 14).